# @Column in the hibernate syntax

Tags: hibernate

I am not familair with Hibernate but still need to make some minor modifications to the code.

In the code I see something like this:

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "patients_possible")
public int patientsPossible;

@Basic
public BigDecimal weight;
```

So my question is why some of these do have the `@column` but some do not? 
But at the top of the file where there is a `@ColumnOrder` command, I see both of them listed as columns in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the columnname in your model differs from the columnname in your database. You're basically letting Hibernate know how the column mapped to your attributename patientsPossible is named in your database.

Comment: oh I see, so "patientsPossible" is the one they call and use in the java code and the patients_possible is the one that is created in DB schema?

Comment: To be exact: the *attribute* name in your model differs from the column name in the database.